# Using Onsubmit function with php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to use onsubmit  javascript event with my php code.

So I have a screen in which I am allowing a user to select a record to delete,when the user presses the submit button.
But I want the user confirm his action when he presses the submit button by displaying a popup by using javascript

I have added onsubmit event like this

`<input type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this record?')" />`

But no pop up or alert message is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `onsubmit` attribute in the `<form>` tag instead of the `<submit>` tag.